# My copy of the app cannot connect to SQL db

Tags: sql-server

Trying to join the development team for a project, I copied the code of the app to my local machine and restored the working db.
But there is something wrong with the way my users are configured and I cannot connect to db

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

This is what I did:

1) in SQL Server mgmt studio Server Properties/Security tab Server Authentication is enabled for "SQL Server and Windows Authentication"

2) Security/Logins user added, login name set for SQL Server auth.

3) Tried mapping this new login to the appropriate user, but get this error:

> Create failed for User, user already exists in the current db

Please help me figure this out!

Comment: When you restored the DB, you also restored that user at the DB level.  If you are trying to recreate it, try dropping the old one first (at the DB level) and recreating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are suffering from a classic problem (it even has a name - orphaned users) where the login and user name internally don't sync up. To fix it you can use the built in proc (for SQL Server 2008 and on):

```
sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', 
@UserNamePattern='ConfusedUser', 
@LoginName='ConfusedUser'
```

and it will be fixed. If you drop the user you have to re-establish all the rights the user had and whatever groups they were in.

Comment: This did work! The user was identified, the comment above I think would also work (The user for db is the one that has to be deleted and re-created)